# How combine the sorted sets Redis?

Tags: php, redis

I use `sorted set` type in Redis store.
For each user I create a own **KEY** and put here data:

Example of **KEY:**

```
FEED:USER:**1**, FEED:USER:**2**, FEED:USER:**3**
```

I want to select data from Redis for user's keys: 1, 2, 3 and sorted each by score (timestamp).

If see at problem simply, I need select from any KEY a data across time and after combine all results sorted by score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this but the right one depends on what you're trying to do. For example:

1. You can use ZRANGEBYSCORE (or ZREVRANGEBYSCORE) in your code for each `FEED:USER:n` key and "merge" the replies in the client
2. You can do a ZUNIONSTORE on the relevant keys and then do the ZRANGEBYSCORE on the result from the client.
3. However, if your "feeds" are large, #2's flow should be reversed - first range and then union.
4. You could also do similar types of processing entirely server-side with some Lua scripting.

**EDIT: further clarifications**

Re. 1 - Merging could be done client-side on the results that you get from ZRANGEBYSCORE or you could use server-side Lua scripts to do that. Use the WITHSCORES to get the timestamp and merge/sort on it. Regardless the your choice of location for running this code (I'd probably use Lua for data locality), the implementation is up to you - lmk if you need help with that :)

Comment: Can you explain more please about paragraph 1. I need an example how to "merge". My score in **Sorted set** is timestamp. If I get items from **FEED:USER:1** and **FEED:USER:2** How then merge these?

Comment: About **2.** item: I am not allowed make **ZUNIONSTORE** because I need select all data from other user, even if their weight is same. After you told to make **ZRANGEBYSCORE**. Do the second query to Redis store? Or only at client side PHP? About **1.** item: I can get all data by each key. But how then to combine data? In what sequence?

Comment: I've tried expanding on #1. Re 2. - I'm not sure that I understand why you can't use ZUNIONSTORE - if the same member exists from two different users the result will still contain it.

Comment: For example at first I use `ZUNIONSTORE`, in result I get the number of merged `KEYS`, how then to LIMIT data? I want get latest 10 notes from each KEYS