# How combine data from Redis?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I use `sorted sets` type in Redis. Each user adds an event to Redis with a score - current timestamp and key: `User:ID_USER`

How I can get 10 latest events from redis store sorted by score(timestamp)?
For this there is a function Z`REVRANGEBYSCORE`, but if use it, I get a problem, because not every user have events at last time score.

**Edited:**
For example, I want to merge some sorted keys by score(timestamp) and selecting the latest data for last 4 hours for each users.

Problem is, that if user did not post data in Redis in this interval(4 hours) then does not show nothing for this user. But I need select latest data sorted by timestamp from each user. Maybe use any function?

Comment: I found a same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257432/how-combine-the-sorted-sets-redis/26257839#26257839 But I have some questions that there are in my current question

Comment: I'm confident your question has an answer but I can't understand the problem :) Could you rephrase/add more details?

Comment: Sorry, still unclear. IIUC you have multiple sorted sets, one for each user, that store events (per user) based on the timestamp (used as the score). You want to merge (ZUNIONSTORE) several such sets to get the n (10) last events from those users (using ZREVRANGEBYSCORE on the resulting set) during an interval (4h). If a user (sorted set) doesn't have an event for that interval, it won't be included in the result (that's filtered on the timestamp).  What is the end result that you're looking for?

Comment: I want to get the latest 10 events from each users(`KEY`) and combine them by score, socted by score timestamp. It will be result of scores and data. Now I can use `ZUNIONSTORE` for each KEY, but there is a many records, so I want to take only 10.

Comment: I think at first I can use `ZRANGE` for get latest 10 keys for each  user. After user `ZUNIONSTORE` for combine selected `KEYS`. Then I get sorted by timestamp KEYS and VALUES